# How to choose which type of buttons to show with PayPal sdk?

Tags: paypal

I'm using the PayPal sdk from here:

```
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/
```

and it gives me the following buttons:

[image]

However, I don't want the Debit or Credit Card button and want to add other buttons like Venmo.  How can I do that? What are all the options of buttons that I can add?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can do it in two places.  I prefer to remove using the SDK command line.

```
     i.e.:<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOURCLIENTID 
     HERE&***disable-funding=credit,card***"></script>
```

using the disable-funding=statement

Also as a note: The disabled funding sources for the transaction. Any funding sources passed are not displayed in the Smart Payment Buttons. By default, funding source eligibility is smartly decided based on a variety of factors. Note: Pass credit in disable-funding for merchants that fall into these categories:Real money gaming merchants
Non-US merchants who do not have the correct licenses and approvals to display the Credit button.

To disable a particular card use disable-card=amex,jcb

Also the country plays a role in which funding options are available and which are not.  then using your button styles you determine which ones you want.  Be aware that some styles such as horizontal vs vertical will not display certain buttons.

Hope this helps

D